# BST and Linked List C program stuck at large values

Tags: c, performance, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I'm doing a college work where the professor asked us to implement BST and linked list and count how many comparisons it makes to insert and search a large amount of randomly-generated values. We're supposed to start at 10 values, then 100, then 1000, up until 10^12. The thing is, it always gets stuck at 100000 (10^5). The RAM usage is low, but CPU is at max. I'm freeing both the tree and lists after each step. The code is found [here](https://codeshare.io/5PJvyw) (offsite) and below.

Just to sum up some important points: each value (the key to the node) is an unsigned it (max 65535), but up to 10^12 values should be inserted and another 10^12 searched.

Is it supposed to take this long? My processor is an i5-7200u

Is there a chance it's a memory problem and GCC is blocking it somehow?

Thanks a lot

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef long long ll;
typedef unsigned long long ull;

// BST

typedef struct no_A_struct {
  unsigned int chave;
  struct no_A_struct *esquerda;
  struct no_A_struct *direita;
} no_A;

// new node
no_A *novo_no_A(unsigned int chave) {
  no_A *no = (no_A *) malloc(sizeof(no_A));
  no->chave = chave;
  no->esquerda = no->direita = NULL;
  return no;
}

// insert note
no_A *insere_A(no_A *raiz, unsigned int chave, ull *cont) {
  (*cont)++; if (raiz == NULL) return novo_no_A(chave);
  (*cont)++; if (chave < raiz->chave) raiz->esquerda = insere_A(raiz->esquerda, chave, cont);
  else {
    (*cont)++; if (chave > raiz->chave) raiz->direita = insere_A(raiz->direita, chave, cont);
  }
  return raiz; 
}

// search node
no_A *busca_A(no_A *raiz, unsigned int chave, ull *cont) {
  (*cont)++; if (raiz == NULL) return NULL;
  (*cont)++; if (chave == raiz->chave) return raiz;
  (*cont)++; if (chave > raiz->chave) return busca_A(raiz->direita, chave, cont);
  return busca_A(raiz->esquerda, chave, cont);
}

// free tree
void desaloca_A(no_A *raiz) { // TODO iterativa?
  if (raiz == NULL) return;
  desaloca_A(raiz->esquerda);
  desaloca_A(raiz->direita);
  free(raiz);
}

// LINKED LIST WITH IN ORDER INSERTION

typedef struct no_L_struct {
  unsigned int chave;
  struct no_L_struct *prox;
} no_L;

// new node
no_L *novo_no_L(unsigned int chave) {
  no_L *no = (no_L *) malloc(sizeof(no_L));
  no->chave = chave;
  no->prox = NULL;
  return no;
}

// insert node
void insere_L(no_L **inicio, unsigned int chave, ull *cont) {
  no_L *novo_no = novo_no_L(chave);
  (*cont)++; if (*inicio == NULL) { *inicio = novo_no; return; }
  (*cont)++; if (novo_no->chave <= (*inicio)->chave) {
    novo_no->prox = *inicio;
    *inicio = novo_no;
  } else {
    no_L *atual = *inicio;
    for (;;) {
      (*cont)++; if (atual->prox == NULL) break;
      (*cont)++; if (novo_no->chave <= atual->prox->chave) break;
      atual = atual->prox;
    }
    novo_no->prox = atual->prox;
    atual->prox = novo_no;
  }
}

// search node
no_L *busca_L(no_L *atual, unsigned int chave, ull *cont) {
  for (;;) {
    (*cont)++; if (atual == NULL) break;
    (*cont)++; if (atual->chave == chave) break;
    atual = atual->prox;
  }
  return atual;
}

// void printa_L(no_L *atual) {
//   if (atual == NULL) return;
//   printf("%u", atual->chave);
//   printa_L(atual->prox);
// }

// free list
void desaloca_L(no_L *atual) {
  no_L *no_apagar;
  while (atual != NULL) {
    no_apagar = atual;
    atual = atual->prox;
    free(no_apagar);
  }
}

int main() {
  ll QTD_VALORES[] = {10, 100, 1000, // 10^: 1, 2, 3
              10000, 100000, 1000000, // 4, 5, 6
              1000000000, 10000000000, // 9, 10
              100000000000, 1000000000000}; // 11, 12
  int ITERACOES = 1; // TODO voltar pra 100
  unsigned int VALOR_MAX = 65535;

  int tamanho_qtd_valores = sizeof(QTD_VALORES)/sizeof(QTD_VALORES[0]);
  srand(time(0));

  for (int qtd_i=0; qtd_i<tamanho_qtd_valores; qtd_i++) {
    ll qtd = QTD_VALORES[qtd_i];
    printf("== QTD DE VALORES %lli ==\n", qtd);

    for (int i=0; i<ITERACOES; i++) {

      ull comp_A_insercao = 0, comp_A_busca = 0,
          comp_L_insercao = 0, comp_L_busca = 0;
      no_A *arvore = NULL;
      no_L *lista = NULL;

      // generates and insert values
      unsigned int valores_busca[qtd];
      for (ll v=0; v<qtd; v++) {
        // // insert values
        unsigned int valor_insercao = rand() % VALOR_MAX + 1;
        arvore = insere_A(arvore, valor_insercao, &comp_A_insercao);
        insere_L(&lista, valor_insercao, &comp_L_insercao);

        valores_busca[v] = rand() % VALOR_MAX + 1;
      }

      // search values
      for (ll v=0; v<qtd; v++) {
        busca_A(arvore, valores_busca[v], &comp_A_busca);
        busca_L(lista, valores_busca[v], &comp_L_busca);
      }

      // desaloca_A(arvore);
      // desaloca_L(lista);

      // TODO divisões retornar numero real?
      printf("INTERACTION %d: \n", i+1);
      printf("Tree insertion, total=%llu, avg=%llu\n", comp_A_insercao,
            comp_A_insercao / qtd);
      printf("Tree search, total=%llu, avg=%llu\n", comp_A_busca,
            comp_A_busca / qtd);
      printf("List insertion, total=%llu, avg=%llu\n", comp_L_insercao,
            comp_L_insercao / qtd);
      printf("List search, total=%llu, avg=%llu\n", comp_L_busca,
            comp_L_busca / qtd);    
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: If the code is "too big" then you need to minimize it so it becomes a [mcve]. Narrow down the problem, for example by removing parts of code that is irrelevant for the problem at hand. If the problem disappears you add the last part you remove back in, and remove something else. When there's nothing you can remove without also removing the problem, you start using a debugger to step through your code, and see when and where it goes wrong.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, It turns out the code is actually quite reasonably short for what it is. I've inlined it into the question.

Comment: Thanks both of you, especially you @ikegami

Comment: Memory shouldn't be an issue. Even if you have 100 bytes of overhead per node, 100,000 nodes would only take 10 MB. When you have memory in the order of GB available, that's nothing.

Comment: Tip: `unsigned int valores_busca[qtd];` will overflow the stack for larger `qtd`. You will need to use `malloc`.   You should use `unsigned int valores_busca[VALOR_MAX + 1];` and initialize it to zero, and `++valores_busca[ rand() % VALOR_MAX + 1 ];`

Comment: Tip: `rand() % VALOR_MAX + 1` (1..65535) should probably be `rand() % ( VALOR_MAX + 1 )` (0..65535)

Comment: Thanks @ikegami! I already corrected the rand. About the valores_busca, I don't think I'm following. Wouldn't it set an array of size 65536, and then increment it on specific indexes?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you use `valores_busca` to later perform searches for each item you added so you can count the total number of comparisons to find them. You don't need to preserve the insertion order (since searching for key 0 then key 1 will have the same number of comparisons as searching for key 1 then key 0). All you need is the number of times you inserted each key (key 0 was inserted `a[0]` times, key 1 was inserted `a[1]` times, etc). Then, using a pair of nested loops (for each element of `a`, as many times as the value of that element, search for the key of that element).

Comment: (Shouldn't you be using `valor_insercao` instead of calling `rand` again?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are supposed to insert items already in the list? I think you're suppose to avoid adding duplicates keys.

---

Inserting the first node in the linked list will requires 0 comparisons. The second, 1/2 (on avg). The third, 2/2, The fourth 3/2, etc. So inserting N times will have a average time proportional to (0+1+2+...+(N-2)+(N-1))/2 = N*(N-1)/4.

```
$ perl -e'printf "%d: %d\n", $_, (10**$_)*(10**$_-1)/4 for 1..5;'
1: 22
2: 2475
3: 249750
4: 24997500
5: 2499975000
```

That's an average time of 2.5 billion time units to insert 10<sup>5</sup> nodes. For example, if it takes 100 ns per comparison, it will take over 4 minutes to insert 10<sup>5</sup> nodes on average.

At that same rate, inserting 10<sup>12</sup> nodes would take an average of 800 million years.

---

If, on the other hand, you avoid adding a key that's already in the list, the average time will be no more than 65,536*N/2

```
$ perl -e'printf "%d: %d\n", $_, 65536*(10**$_-1)/4 for 1..12;'
1: 147456
2: 1622016
3: 16367616
4: 163823616
5: 1638383616
6: 16383983616
7: 163839983616
8: 1638399983616
9: 16383999983616
10: 163839999983616
11: 1638399999983616
12: 16383999999983616
```

So instead of taking 800 million years, inserting 10<sup>12</sup> nodes will take an average of "only" 19 days using the rate assumed above. Even if I'm off by an order of magnitude, we're still talking about 2 days.

Comment: Thanks for you thorough answer. Yes, in theory you shouldn't be able to insert duplicated keys on a structure. But my professor provided us a pseudocode where nothing like this was present.

My conclusion is that what he's asking is absurd. I'll make an analysis based on up to 10^5 and talk to him later. Thans a lot!